# ARM Assembly: Concatenate 2 Strings from memory

Tags: arm

SIMPLE ARM LANGUAGE, keep the answers simple please

```
    AREA one, CODE
        ENTRY
        LDR r0, =STRING1
        LDR r1, =STRING2
        LDR r3, =STRING3

`loop1` LDRB r4, [r0], #1
        STRB r4, [r3], #1
        CMP r0, #0x00
        BNE loop1

loop2   LDRB r4, [r1], #1
        STRB r4, [r3], #1
        CMP r1, #0x00
        BNE loop2

        LDRB r4, #0x00
        STRB r4, [r3]

        ALIGN
STRING1 DCB "This is a test string1"            ;String1
EoS1    DCB 0x00                                ;end of string1
STRING2 DCB "This is a test string2"            ;String
EoS2    DCB 0x00                                ;end of string2
STRING3 space 0xFF 
        END
```

Im trying to concatenate `STRING1` and `STRING2` and store result in `STRING3` and also append NULL End Of String `0x00`

Is this correct?

Comment: "Is this correct?" Well, does it give the expected result when you run it? Have you stepped through it in a debugger to verify it does what you think it does? Have a think about the significance of storing the character to the output string _before_ you've checked if it's zero, and consider whether that's a problem, or something you can be clever and take more advantage of.

Comment: Every time i step through the STRB it give NO WRITE PERMISSION.?

Comment: you are comparing r0 (the address) with zero, but you should be comparing r4 (the value) with zero. also put your cmp after the ldrb and only write if not equal (strbne), because you don't want to write the zero

Answer (score 1):

you are getting 'NO write permission' because you must set the Memory Map in the Debug Tab of the Kiel simulator to Read/Write/Execute permission